# Daily upload of file automation using batch script and WinSCP

Tags: windows, batch-file, task, scheduler, winscp

So I do have a file that I generate weekly from a server using crontab in Linux side and transfer it to my PC. However, I am having a problem when try to send the file that I generate from a different server on Windows side using task scheduler.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Task Scheduler failed to launch action "winscp.com" in instance "{8d4a972f-f997-48dd-90fa-71e2f0b2b974}" of task "\binver_transaction". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942402. @SomethingDark

Comment: That's the error code for "file not found." It looks like you may be using a relative path somewhere where you should be using the full path.

Comment: I've already double checked it but somehow my file path is correct. Btw, does it have to do with the Admin rights?? @SomethingDark

Comment: Can you show us a complete command of your scheduler task?

Comment: command: winscp.com
trigger: /script=C:\batchrun\Binver\script.tmp /log="C:\BIN VERIFICATION\ftplog"\ftpBinverlog_%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command-line syntax is wrong.

I'm assuming the `\ftpBinverlog_%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%.txt` is the file, you want to download.

- It won't work, if you just specify it on command-line like you did.
- Also neither Windows scheduler, nor command-interpreter, nor WinSCP understand syntax like `%yyyy%`.
- The path to the remote file does not look good either. *nix systems use forward slashes, not backslashes.

So just keep your `/script` and `/log` arguments:

```
/script=C:\batchrun\Binver\script.tmp /log="C:\BIN VERIFICATION\ftplog"
```

And make sure the `script.tmp` looks like:

```
open sftp://user@example.com
get /ftpBinverlog_%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%.txt C:\target_path\
exit
```

References:

- [Guide to automating file transfer from SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [`%TIMESTAMP` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Develop a batch file which will download/upload the required file using the `SCP` command 
check [this](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/09/23/command-line-scp-for-windows/) for more details.

check [this](http://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/) for more details about the scp command parameters.

Make sure that you are able to run the batch with a successful result, then configure it within a scheduled task.

I hope this could help.