# what am i doing wrong here if i have a batch file calling a txt file with the code below and my expected result is MyFile_20200804.zip

Tags: batch-file

```
echo off
Set Today=%Date:~8,2%%Date:~5,2%%Date:~2,2%

option batch abort
option confirm off

open sftp://Username:Password@HostName -hostkey="my host key"
get MyFile_%Today%.zip  "E:\MyFolder\"
```

Expected result `MyFile_20200804.zip`

Comment: `option ..`, `open..` etc. These are not default `cmd` commands, but instead are `WinScp` commands. Did you attempt reading the documentation for `WinScp`? typically we store the commands in an answer file and run winscp to read from it. see this [`example`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#commands)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Daily upload of file automation using batch script and WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241038/daily-upload-of-file-automation-using-batch-script-and-winscp)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have WinScp installed, so unable to test this, but you need to create an answer file, let's call it `myfile.txt`, you however need to create the date variable in the file, so we could let the batch file create the text file for you:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set result=%%i
(
  echo option batch abort
  echo option confirm off
  echo open sftp://Username:Password@HostName -hostkey="my host key"
  echo get "MyFile_%result:~0,8%.zip"  "E:\MyFolder\" 
  echo exit
)>myfile.txt
winscp.com /ini=nul /script=myfile.txt
```

You will note that I used `wmic os get localdatetime` instead of the locale specific `%date%` variable. If you have different regional settings, your script will fail collecting the file using `%date%` simply because of various date formats available.

Comment: the script doesnt give me the date part so i end up searching for MyFile_.zip

Comment: Did you copy everything as is? only changed your server and userinfo? open `cmd` and run `for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %i in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set result=%i`, press enter then run `echo %result:~0,8%` and let me know the output.

Comment: the output is 20200804

Comment: ok, so then it must work. Copy everything as is, then ONLY change your actual file `MyFile_` and your server detail, do not change variables `%result%` or `%result:~0,8%`

Comment: Thank, this worked, i made a mistake at first when i edited the get part.....thank you sir